# Dynamically loading content on user input with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I created an e-commerce website with PHP on which you can choose filter options to dynamically show the matching contents without page reload.

Whenever the user changes a filter option a javascript function will be called which sends the values of all the options to a self-built PHP API (with AJAX JQuery) which handles the request, reads the whole mysql database table of "Products", filters them according to the chosen filter options (in PHP) and sends back a json file with all the matching products.

It's working perfectly fine but I am concerned about the performance and reliability.
Escpecially if lots of users visit the page and change the options multiple times simultaneously.
Therefore I would like to know if the database could crash due to many requests and if you could tell me about the best practices on how to handle this approach of dynamically loading content.

I thought about saving the contents of the mysql database table in a seperate json or .txt file and then read from that rather than making databse requests all the time.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. I do think that the website should be able to handle it. Many accesses are after all what dbs are for. But keep in mind, I am not an expert, and happy to be corrected

Comment: Don't try to optimize early. If indeed your metrics show that your site is slow, *then* look for a way to reduce the load. Right now, it's like fixing a problem you don't have.

Comment: In terms of performance and reliability, Ajax and "Page Loading" data requests will be having similar resource consumption. Querying db is even better than querying TXT in terms of performance. You should instead check whether your db can be further optimized by say adding indexes on relevant data fields / retrieving the database fields only you need on queries

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they helped me a lot!

Comment: From MySQL command prompt, could you post TEXT results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE variable_name LIKE 'long_query%' OR variable_name LIKE '%log%'; for a quick check on your configuration - to ensure your Slow Query Log will be available and for a reasonable long_query_time.